# Can This sms (include áéíóú ñ) send in one message？

Tags: android, sms

I have a question. My Sms context is below, can it send in one message?

> Este mensaje prueba la capacidad del equipo para enviar mensajes
>   cortos de longitud 160 caracteres. Se prueban los siguientes
>   caracteres: 1234567890 áéíóú ñ¿?¡!

This message is 160 caracteres, as we know ,7-bit 160 ,8-bit 140 ,us-2 70 .
"áéíóú ñ" is not 7-bit but 8-bit, So I think it can not send it in one message.

But my customer said it must be sent in one message.

If somebody have experience in it, help me to confirm it.

Comment: Android SMS for different language.
There are sLanguageTables and sLanguageShiftTables in GsmAlphabet.java. People need to set correct shift table here for different language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sms messages do not use a regular ascii 7-bit character set.  Wikipedia has a good explanation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38).  Short answer, you might be able to get it into the required 160 characters if you use the correct National language shift table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The spanish sms function is wrong before I set the shift table. There is no problem about send or recevie now.

Este mensaje prueba la capacidad del equipo para enviar mensajes cortos de longitud 160 caracteres. Se prueban los siguientes caracteres: 1234567890 áéíóú ñ**bold**message split into 2 messages**¿?¡!

Comment: Ah, I see my answer was wrong... "Using a shift table, a message can still use 7-bit encoding for the characters ... This allows up to 155 characters, encoded in 136 octets".  I.e. 140 - 4 octets for User Data Header shift table and language code.  I'm afraid you'll need two messages (you could always suggest to your customer to strip the diacriticals ;-)

Comment: The url http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38 is usefull to me. It needs some bit to store User Data Header. So This allows up to 155 characters。 thanks